# Excel VBA Application-defined or object-defined error with PasteSpecial

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to paste from my clipboard and am running into this error:

```
Run-time error ' 1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

when running this line of code:

```
Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("InputSheet").Range("D8").PasteSpecial Format:="Text"
```

However, this line works perfectly fine:

```
Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("InputSheet").Range("D8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

I need to use the `Format:="Text"` line because I'm (usually) copy/pasting from another excel instance and I only want to paste the contents.

It happens if I have three cells copied, or 300 - error every time.

Any suggestions? What am I missing here...

---

** **EDIT** **

After reading over Ben's comment, I changed my code to this and it's doing what I'd like; however, I do wonder if there is a cleaner way to do it.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("InputSheet").Range("D8").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

Comment: `Range.PasteSpecial` does not have a `Format` parameter. Nor is `"Text"` a valid parameter at all. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) might be helpful.

Comment: Side note: `Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)` -> `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the feedback. When I record a macro, I get this `Range("K13").Select ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False` which makes it look like `"Text"` is valid at least in some cases!

Comment: @BigBen Well, my solution works if I paste from somewhere outside of my sheet - which is what I will be doing most of the time. It does look to get stuck when trying to paste from the same sheet though.

Comment: That is because `ActiveSheet` is not a `Range`. The recorded code is using the [`Worksheet.PasteSpecial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pastespecial) method, not the `Range.PasteSpecial` method.